# Есть ли на MAC gedit как на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mac

Есть ли на MAC gedit как на Ubuntu?

Comment: В маке обычно в этом случае используют textmate https://github.com/textmate/textmate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Есть. Может взять тут [Скачать GEdit](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/mac/gedit/3.2/).

Comment: установил gedit-3.2.6-3_SnowLeopard_64bit. написал в терминале gedit main.cpp выдал ошибку command not found. открыл в applications выдал ошибку

Comment: @NursultanKenzhegaliyev По умолчанию GEdit не прописывает себя в PATH. Вы можете либо запустить его из Application, либо запустить из терминала используя команду `open /Applications/gedit.app`